# FileOutputStream giving null pointer exception

Tags: android

I'm having an issue trying to save a file to inernal memory. It seems there is a problem with initializing the file for writing, and I can't seem to figure out why. Is there something I'm missing?

I am getting a NPE at:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

My code:

```
try {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    osw.write(jsonString);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                    Log.d("Cache", "Cache Complete");
                    runesCached = true;

                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure about the location of the NPE?

Comment: Are you calling it within a Context?

Comment: where is the "runesInfo.json" file located ?

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE makes no sense as the internalFilesDir is only accessable for the app itself. Try with MODE_PRIVATE. Android version?

Comment: @Hitman I was under the impression that this would create the file for me. It seems that is incorrect.

Comment: you are opening the file, so if there is no file at the giving path, there is nothing to open